# Why can I instantiate classes with abstract methods in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-class, abstract

I noticed that a class with an `abstractmethod` can still be instantiated if it does not inherit from `ABC`. This seems to be in contrast with the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod):

> Using this decorator requires that the class’s metaclass is ABCMeta or is derived from it. A class that has a metaclass derived from ABCMeta cannot be instantiated unless all of its abstract methods and properties are overridden.

From this I would understand that

1. Adding `@abstractmethod` to a method will not be accepted by Python if that class doesn't have `ABCMeta` as metaclass
2. Even if it is, that class can not be instantiated

I drafted the following example:

```
from abc import abstractmethod, ABC


class TestClassOne:
    @abstractmethod
    def test_method(self):
        ...


class TestClassTwo(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def test_method(self):
        ...


test_object_one = TestClassOne()
test_object_two = TestClassTwo()
```

Runnig on Python 3.9.13 or 3.11.3 gives the output

> TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class TestClassTwo with abstract method test_method

but notably this error does not mention `TestClassOne`.

Am I misunderstanding something here or could this be a bug in Python?

Comment: I think your 1. means that the decorator only works if the metaclass is used, not that the decorator will not be allowed.

Comment: The point is that it's the `ABCMeta` class that implements the instantiation restriction. And the decorator tells it which methods it should check for when doing this. So you have to use these two features together to make it happen. Either of them by itself does nothing.

Comment: Python doesn't enforce the use of `ABC` together with decorators because none of this is a syntactical Python feature. It's just implemented using generic Python techniques that together imitate the behaviour of abstract classes found in other languages at a parser level.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies! If one of you could post your reply as answer, I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ABCMeta` metaclass and the `@abstractmethod` decorator work together to prevent instantiation of a class that doesn't implement the required methods. Each of them has no effect without the other.

So if you define an abstract base class without any `@abstractmethod` decorators, it allows instantiation -- it's not *really* abstract.

And if you use `@abstractmethod` in a non-ABC, it's ignored because it's the metaclass that actually implements the enforcement. This decorator simply registers the method as requiring an override in the subclass.